# Go get error while getting major version module dependency

Tags: go, go-modules, go-get, go-build, go-packages

I have an executable go module and i am trying to execute the below command

```
go get github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2
```

and get this error:

```
module github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation@upgrade found (v1.0.1), but does not contain package github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2
```

**number-manipulation** is a non-executable go module with the following tags
v1.0.0, v1.0.1 and v2.0.0.

I am new to go. So someone please tell me what is the issue here.

Module with main package

**app.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/calc"
    calcNew "github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2/calc"
)

func main() {
    result := calc.Add(1, 2)
    fmt.Println("calc.Add(1,2) =>", result)

    result = calc.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    fmt.Println("calc.Add(1,2,3,4,5) =>", result)

    newResult, err = calcNew.Add()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: =>", error)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("calcNew.Add(1,2,3,4) =>", calcNew.Add(1, 2, 3, 4))
    }
}
```

**go.mod**

```
module main

go 1.14

require github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation v1.0.1
```

**go version go1.14.3 darwin/amd64**

**go env**

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOPATH="/Users/<user-id>/Golang"
GOMOD="/Users/<user-id>/GoModules/main/go.mod"
```

I tried set GO111MODULE=on; but that doesnt change the value of GO111MODULE

```
# go build app.go 

go: finding module for package github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2/calc

app.go:7:2: module github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation@latest found (v1.0.1), but does not contain package github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2/calc
```

Comment: the repo doesn't contain a v2 package. maybe you want to specify the version v2: go get github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation@v2. go.mod file must have: require github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation v2

Comment: I am getting this go get github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation@v2: no matching versions for query "v2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your github module `go.mod` file looks like:

```
module github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation

go 1.14
```

Whereas your client code is importing `v2`:

```
calcNew "github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2/calc"
```

---

If you want to use the version tagged `v2.0.0` you need to change the github module's `go.mod` file to:

```
module github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2

go 1.14
```

Note that this forces you to change also import paths *within the library* itself.

And then require the `v2` path into your client go.mod file:

```
module main

go 1.14

require github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation/v2 v2.0.0
```

Comment: I have v1.0.1 and v2.0.0 version of the module. I want to use both the versions in my main module. v1.0.1 tag is there on master and v2.0.0 tag is there on v2 branch of my number-manipulation module

Comment: @java_geek regardless of the branch, you are attempting to import a `v2` path in your client code, whereas the `go.mod` file of the library (both in master and v2 branches) defines the module as `module github.com/saipraveen-a/number-manipulation`. You have to push a fix to your v2 branch and add a `v2` suffix to the `module` path, otherwise you can't `require` the `v2.0.0` tag